# Why I cannot get the key list of a dictionary in Python3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

I am learning Python. I tried to get the keys of a dictionary. But I only get the last key. In my understanding, method keys() is used to get all keys in the dictionary.

Following are my questions?

```
1. Why I cannot get all keys? 
2. If I have a dictionary, how can I get the value if I know the key? e.g. dict = {'Ben':8, 'Joe':7, 'Mary' : 9}. How can I input the key = "Ben", so the program can output the value 8? The tutorial shows that the key must be immutable. This constraint is very inconvenient when trying to get a value with a given key.
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Here are my code.

```
import os, tarfile, urllib

work_path = os.getcwd()
input_control_file = "input_control"
import os, tarfile, urllib

work_path = os.getcwd()
input_control_file = "input_control"
input_control= work_path + "/" + input_control_file

#open control file if file exist
#read setting info
try:
   #if the file does not exist,
   #then it would throw an IOError
   f = open(input_control, 'r')

   #define dictionary/hash table
   for LINE in f:
      LINE = LINE.strip()     #remove leading and trailing whitespace
      lst = LINE.split()      #split string into lists
      lst[0] = lst[0].split(":")[0]
      dic = {lst[0].strip():lst[1].strip()}

except IOError:
   # print(os.error) will <class 'OSError'>
   print("Reading file error. File " + input_control + " does not      exist.")

#get keys
def getkeys(dict):
   return list(dict.keys())
print("l39")
print(getkeys(dic))
print("end")
```

Below are the outputs.

```
l39
['source_type']
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are reassigning variable `dic` again in for loop. You are not updating or adding the dictionary, instead you are reassigning the variable. In that case, `dic` will have only the last entry. You can change your `for` loop to:

```
dic = {}
for LINE in f:
    LINE = LINE.strip()     #remove leading and trailing whitespace
    lst = LINE.split()      #split string into lists
    lst[0] = lst[0].split(":")[0]
    dic.update({lst[0].strip():lst[1].strip()}) # update the dictionary with new values.
```

For your other question, if you have the dictionary `dic = {'Ben':8, 'Joe':7, 'Mary' : 9}`, then you can get the value by: `dic['Ben']`. It will return the value `8` or will raise `KeyError` if key `Ben` is not found in the dictionary. To avoid `KeyError`, you can use the `get()` method of dictionary. It will return `None` if provided key is not found in the dictionary.

```py
val = dic['Ben'] # returns 8
val = dic['Hen'] # will raise KeyError
val = dic.get('Hen') # will return None
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I still could not get all keys. Any suggestion?

Comment: In addition, when I give the key="Ben", I get none. Is there any reasons?

Comment: can you confirm that all keys having different values? keys should be unique, if there are multiple keys with same name, then only last key will used.

Comment: you should not get `None` if key is available. also don't use reserve keywords like `dict`, use some other variable name

Comment: Yes. I got it. The improper indentation resulted in my errors. I sincerely appreciate your help and time.

Comment: sometime some odd spacing can change the flow, happened with me as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you are re-initializing the dictionary value, while you need to update the dictionary, i.e., append the key-value pair to the pre-existing dictionary. For this, use 
`dic.update({lst[0].strip() : lst[1].strip()})`
This will update the key-value pair to the dictionary. Now, when you use `dic.keys()`, you will get all the keys of `dic`, as a list.

As for your second question, access the dictionary, just like accessing a list, except that list is accessed with indices, and dictionary will be accessed by keys. Say, you have a list and a dictionary as

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dic = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4, 'e' : 5}
```

To get value 2 from list, you do `lst[1]`, i.e., value at index 1. Similarly, if you want to get the value 2 from dictionary, do `dic['b']`, i.e., value of key 'b'. It is as simple as that.